# How to add front end to already deployed backend project (same repo)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, express, heroku

I currently have a Node.js project with this file structure:

```
strava-descriptions/
├── .DS_Store
├── .env
├── .eslintrc.js
├── .git
├── .gitignore
├── authorizeStrava.js
├── buildDescription.js
├── config.js
├── db.js
├── getActivity.js
├── getSongsPlayedDuringActivity.js
├── getSpotifyAccessToken.js
├── getSpotifyRecentlyPlayed.js
├── getStravaAccessToken.js
├── getWeatherConditions.js
├── handleWebhookEvent.js
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── server.js
└── updateDescription.js
```

The parent folder `strava-descriptions` is its own GitHub repository and is also deployed to Heroku.

What I want to have happen is to put all of these files into a sub-directory called `backend`, and create a new `frontend` folder in `strava-descriptions` to house a React front end. However, I know that using `create-react-app` will create its own git repo inside the `frontend` folder.

My question is, how do I accomplish this without totally messing up my Heroku deployment and current GitHub repo? Ideally I would like to have one complete project on GitHub (frontend and backend together), but have them deployed and functioning as two separate apps.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use `create-react-app` to initialize you project and then just paste the files on your old repository, reorganize the files and then you can manage you builds for react with npm